# Render Partial View with Object Model using jquery / Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.renderpartial

My current code looks like

```
<!-- some html -->
{
    // some code
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/AdminUser/Main.cshtml", Model.AdminUserModel)
}
```

however, i need this to instead be an ajax call.   How do I do an jquery ajax call where the model is included in the call?

Comment: What you could do is make an ajax call with a url query. Set the variables based on your query string.

Comment: problem with that solution is the model could be huge.  mainly need to know how to pass the model.

Comment: was thinking you could possibly make the ajax call include a json (stringify?) version of the model and on the back-end put the model back into the object?   not quite sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I do it is an ajax call passing the id:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@(Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { id = "----" }))/".replace("----", id),
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    success: function (result) {
         $(".Class").html(result);
    }
});
```

and then in your controller have the action set up like

```
public PartialViewResult Action(string id)
{
     //Build your model
     return PartialView("_PartialName", model);
}
```

if you do need to pass a model to the controller through ajax,  if you create a jquery object that has the same fields as the model and stringify and pass it, it will come through correctly.

```
var toSend = {};
toSend.ID = id;
toSend.Name = name;
```

etc,  then in the ajax call

```
data: JSON.stringify(toSend),
```